# How do I let Git show progression during a clone or checkout?

Tags: git, progress

I'm currently working on a tool (in C#, which isn't relevant) that simplifies some git-related tasks for my daily needs by running commands in the command-line in the background. For this to work nicely (user-friendly), I want to show progression during a time consuming tasks, e.g. *[git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)* or *[git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)*, so I can parse those values into proper progress reporting in my tool.

While both `clone` and `checkout` offer the `--progress` options (and additionally `clone` also offers `--verbose`), I can't seem to get that to work properly. Sometimes I indeed see progress updates like below, but 9 out of 10 times it doesn't show anything.

> Checking out files: 43% (12345/67890), done.

Now I've come across *[this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234357/what-controls-git-checkout-feedback)*, but my question remains unanswered because that topic implies that the missing progress reporting was kind-of a bug which has been fixed already.

I'm using git version 2.15.1.windows.2, downloaded via [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Comment: May I ask why you need/want this feature?  I don't seem to recall long wait times for most Git operations, save perhaps a full clone which doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I intend to use this to do local clones of previously made tags from multiple repositories. Let's say that I have 4 "version-chained" repositories (one contains various software platforms, another contains products, another contains deployment settings and another contains version-specific wiki-websites), where each tag contains a version that needs a specific tag from another repository. In order to fix some bug for a deployed system, I need copies of those specific versions while being able to continue working on the "main" stream, because compiling everything takes a while.

Comment: A bit more concrete: when I need to do maintenance on some old system, I clone each relevant version from all repositories into separate directories, do some testing/fixing, then compile the whole thing (each version knows where batch files from other repository-versions exist), and deploy the system with the versioned settings.

I'm fairly new to git, so I could be doing thing entirely wrong (please let me know if that's the case :-)) Otherwise, I'd like to have progression in my tool, because cloning/checking out also takes a while. The repositories are quite large.

Comment: You might also look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859873/1256452 - I am not sure if the `-v` / `--progress` bug is fixed but if not, you literally can't quite get what you want.